# How to match a string from playbook output?

Tags: string, ansible, stdout

I am trying to create a report based on my routers version to check which one has the correct version and which one is not.But somehow even I am putting the exact match of the version, it still return with R1 and R2 has has IOS mismatch.
Could you have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong please?

Here is the code:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - file: path=/etc/ansible/version_report.txt state=absent
  - file: path=/etc/ansible/version_report.txt state=touch

- hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - ios_command:
      commands: show version
      provider: "{{cli}}"
    register: result
  - debug: var=result
  - lineinfile:
      dest:  /etc/ansible/version_report.txt
      regexp: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
      line:   "{{inventory_hostname}}: IOS version mismatch"
    when: "not ('Version {{version}}' in result.stdout[0])"
```

here is the result of the playbook:

```
TASK [lineinfile] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: not ('Version {{version}}' in result.stdout[0])

skipping: [R1]
 [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: not ('Version {{version}}' in result.stdout[0])

skipping: [R2]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
R1                         : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
R2                         : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

here are my variables:

```
location: Building2
syslog_host: 10.96.7.8
version: "15.4(3)S3"
cli:
 transport: cli
root@virtual-machine:/etc/ansible# cat group_vars/ios.yml  
---
syslog_host: 10.97.6.5
location: Building6 
version: "03.13.03.S - Extended Support Release"
cli:
 transport: cli
```

and here  is the output of one of my routers:

```
  R1#sh ver
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 03.13.03.S - Extended Support Release
Cisco IOS Software, CSR1000V Software (X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.4(3)S3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2015 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Thu 28-May-15 13:02 by mcpre
```

and if I checked my report.txt this is what I am getting.

```
virtual-machine:/etc/ansible# cat playbooks/version_report.txt 
R1: IOS version mismatch
R2: IOS version mismatch
```

Here  is the debug stdout:

```
ok: [R2] => {
    "result.stdout[0]": "Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 03.13.03.S - Extended Support Release\nCisco IOS Software, CSR1000V Software (X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.4(3)S3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)\nTechnical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport\nCopyright (c) 1986-2015 by Cisco Systems, Inc.\nCompiled Thu 28-May-15 13:02 by mcpre\n\n\nCisco IOS-XE software, Copyright (c) 2005-2015 by cisco Systems, Inc.\nAll rights reserved.  Certain components of Cisco IOS-XE software are\nlicensed under the GNU General Public License (\"GPL\") Version 2.0.  The\nsoftware code licensed under GPL Version 2.0 is free software that comes\nwith ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  You can redistribute and/or modify such\nGPL code under the terms of GPL Version 2.0.  For more details, see the\ndocumentation or \"License Notice\" file accompanying the IOS-XE software,\nor the applicable URL provided on the flyer accompanying the IOS-XE\nsoftware.\n\n\nROM: IOS-XE ROMMON\n\nR2 uptime is 32 weeks, 2 days, 14 hours, 47 minutes\nUptime for this control processor is 32 weeks, 2 days, 14 hours, 51 minutes\nSystem returned to ROM by reload\nSystem image file is \"bootflash:packages.conf\"\nLast reload reason: <NULL>\n\n\n\nThis product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United\nStates and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and\nuse. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply\nthird-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.\nImporters, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for\ncompliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you\nagree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable\nto comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.\n\nA summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:\nhttp://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html\n\nIf you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to\nexport@cisco.com.\n\nLicense Level: ax\nLicense Type: Default. No valid license found.\nNext reload license Level: ax\n\ncisco CSR1000V (VXE) processor (revision VXE) with 794186K/6147K bytes of memory.\nProcessor board ID 9CGYDZIMALX\n5 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces\n32768K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.\n2506280K bytes of physical memory.\n7774207K bytes of virtual hard disk at bootflash:.\n\nConfiguration register is 0x2102"
}
```

Here is the verbose output for the linefile task:

```
TASK [lineinfile] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/check-version-withoutcurlybrackets.yml:15
skipping: [R1] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", 
    "skipped": true
}
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/files/lineinfile.py
<192.168.1.2> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.168.1.2> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.2> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/nanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1509412236.83-100172408761466 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1509412236.83-100172408761466="` echo /home/nanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1509412236.83-100172408761466 `" ) && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.2> PUT /tmp/tmp3uMTqV TO /home/nanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1509412236.83-100172408761466/lineinfile.py
<192.168.1.2> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/nanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1509412236.83-100172408761466/ /home/nanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1509412236.83-100172408761466/lineinfile.py && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.2> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/nanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1509412236.83-100172408761466/lineinfile.py; rm -rf "/home/nanis/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1509412236.83-100172408761466/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [R2] => {
    "backup": "", 
    "changed": false, 
    "diff": [
        {
            "after": "", 
            "after_header": "version_report.txt (content)", 
            "before": "", 
            "before_header": "version_report.txt (content)"
        }, 
        {
            "after_header": "version_report.txt (file attributes)", 
            "before_header": "version_report.txt (file attributes)"
        }
    ], 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null, 
            "backrefs": false, 
            "backup": false, 
            "content": null, 
            "create": false, 
            "delimiter": null, 
            "dest": "version_report.txt", 
            "directory_mode": null, 
            "follow": false, 
            "force": null, 
            "group": null, 
            "insertafter": null, 
            "insertbefore": null, 
            "line": "R2: IOS version mismatch", 
            "mode": null, 
            "owner": null, 
            "path": "version_report.txt", 
            "regexp": "R2", 
            "remote_src": null, 
            "selevel": null, 
            "serole": null, 
            "setype": null, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "src": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "unsafe_writes": null, 
            "validate": null
        }
    }, 
    "msg": ""
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
R1                         : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
R2                         : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: according to what people marking is as it needs more research ? could someone elaborate please? is there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems a directory issue. the file(version-report.txt) that I created was under etc/ansible but the playbook creates a result verstion-report.txt file under the local directory.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a hint from the warning you get:

> [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: not ('Version {{version}}' in result.stdout[0])

And fix your code:

```
when: "not (('Version ' + version) in result.stdout[0])"
```

<sup>Might not require parentheses around the string concatenation. Also, given your version-string,
I'm not sure you need concatenation at all, but the question asks for it.</sup>

Comment: thanks Techraf , so how i can pass the version variable to: 
(('Version ' + version). you mean I should type it as (('Version ' + 03.13.03.S) ?

Comment: No. I meant what I posted.

Comment: I changed it to that but it still did not give the correct output. it is still claiming that the routers has IOS mismatch
  when: "not (('Version ' + version) in result.stdout[0])"
virtual-machine:/etc/ansible# more playbooks/version_report.txt 
R1: IOS version mismatch
R2: IOS version mismatch

and yes you are right I am not getting the delimiter errors anymore?